# Applying Decision Tree Rules to Unseen Data

Tags: r, weka, decision-tree

Suppose I create a simple decision tree using rpart or J48 from weka where my tree has two possible terminal outputs.

Rather than take the rules built by the tree that I can see visually and hard code them.  How can I read my rpart or weka object dynamically take the rules that were generated on my training data and apply it to my test data?

Comment: You may have to explain in considerably more detail what you mean, because as it stands it simply sounds like you need to use the `predict` function (at least, for **rpart**).

Comment: Agree. And if you want coding examples all you would need to do would be to look at the predict method code.

Comment: If you use the [rweka](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/index.html) package, a call to the classifier gives you an object that you can use with `predict`.

Comment: Actually exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.